# Плагин для браузера (Mozzila FireFox)

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, плагин

Всем Здравствуйте!

У меня есть интерне-магазин, есть также сайт поставщика. 
Чтобы облегчить себе работу я решил написать парсер продуктов с сайта поставщика, но нужны мне не все продукты, а только те, которые я выберу.

Для опыта пришла в голову мысль сделать вообще плагин для лисы, чтобы на сайте около продуктов появилась кнопочка "Добавить ко мне в магазин" и плагин автоматически парсил продукт и отправлял мне на обработчик данные о товаре, и кидал их в базу.

**На чём пишутся такие плагины для лисы? И как они пишутся? Есть какие-то примеры?**
Боже, первый раз встречаю такое на этом форуме, откуда столько минусов. Люди не знают, видят что в яндексе есть ссылочки и ругаются сразу. А вопрос интересный, интересная задача.
Форум же для обмена опытом!

Comment: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/ тут тоже были?

Comment: да, уже зарегистрировался там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCOM плагины - пишутся на чем угодно(любые высокоуровневые ЯП), NPAPI же.

Далее обычные дополнения, ну тут сложнее: 
Есть на XUL, а с недавнего времени появился Add-on SDK(есть расширение JetPack) там все на JavaScript. Вам в любом случае надо будет изучать JavaScript, HTML ну и CSS, чтоб було красиво.

Если тесная взаимосвязь именно с FF не сильно нужна, можете воспользоваться готовыми фреймворками типа:
[Kango Framework](http://kangoextensions.com/)
и
[Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/)

Вторым я не пользовался. Kango прост как вилка, бонусом ваше дополнение будет работать в Opera и Chrome и Safari, Internet Explorer только в коммерческой версии. 
В демках есть пример вставки новогодней елки в тело станицы.

Знания: Ну преимущественно JavaScript, HTML, CSS шоб було красиво.

P.S. То что вы ищите, называется использование Content Script'ов.
А регируют на вас негативно, вот за что:

> На чём пишутся такие плагины для лисы? И как они пишутся? Есть какие-то примеры?

Сразу говорит о вашем нежелании самостоятельно найти ответ на элементарный вопрос "Создание расширений для FireFox"

Comment: Понятно, огромное спасибо!! JS, HTML, CSS прекрасно знаю, 5 лет занимаюсь разработкой сайтов) Я искал информацию, потом понял, что мне придётся разбираться во всей системе этих плагинов, и потом ещё может и не получится. Решил задать вопрос у опытных людей, чтобы сразу указали на что-то. Ещё раз спасибо за хороший ответ!